# opening a txt file, in 'with' statement, SyntaxError keeps appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep receiving in my view a very odd SyntaxError. I do a basic txt file reading. I have changed my code, I even have switched from python v2 to v3 file. The error keeps appearing. Your advice would be highly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:   # SyntaxError: invalid syntax - showing ^ on 'with'
    for line in f.readlines():
        for i in line.split(","):
            i = i[1:-1]
            print("\n", i)
            function_v(i)
```

Since this code seems I believe correct, I put it in a function, but now the function given me the same error:

```
def open_f(file_inp):  # SyntaxError: invalid syntax - now showing ^ on def
    with open(file_inp, "r") as f:
# below function:
open_f("test.txt")  # to call function
```

The first code remains the same, indented under the function.
To simplify, I have also put "test.txt" in the same folder as python file.
I have rebooted my computer, I have tried in another shell. I am not sure why this error shows.
Thank you.

Comment: It's the line above it. 99% of the time with a syntax error, it's the line above.

Comment: Your first example is correct.

Comment: No syntax error for me with the code you've given. Maybe post more of the code as Morgan Thrapp suggests.

Comment: @ Morgan Thrapp: thank you, that is correct. Commenting out the previous line gets me over this hurdle :)